# How to get Bitmap from MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, uri)?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera-intent, mediastore

I am having difficulties with retrieving a bitmap from my uri. I am trying to fetch the image taken from camera after opening the camera via an Intent.

```
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), createImageFile());
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);   // set the image file name
                        }
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

The imageUri when logged is

> content://com.example/external_files/Pictures/CustomFolder/15122017_photo_115344.jpg

After the camera is opened and the picture taken, my onActivityResult is called. Because I use MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT I do not receive anything in my data object it is null. I try to use MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap() to retrieve the bitmap. I pass in the imageUri. I believe this may be incorrect because I receive an exception.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                ivProfilePhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){

        }
    }
```

The exception I receive is

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory

EDIT:

I can hang on to the File, but this does not seem to work either. Here is what I have tried. I updated my intent to be the following

```
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            mFile = createImageFile();
                            imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), mFile);
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);   // set the image file name
                        }
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Then in onActivityResult, I do the following

```
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getPath());
            ivProfilePhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Nothing gets set for the image. Also, for your FYI this is how I am creating my directory and setting my file image name.

```
private File createImageFile() {
    File imgFileDir = getDir();
    if (!imgFileDir.exists() && !imgFileDir.mkdirs()) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "Directory does not exist");
        imgFileDir.mkdirs();
    }
    Logger.e("TEST", "imgFileDir= " + imgFileDir);
    // Locale.US to get local formatting
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmmss", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy", Locale.US);
    String time = timeFormat.format(new Date());
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    String photoFile = date + "_photo_" + time + ".jpg";
    filename = imgFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

    Logger.i(TAG, "time(hhmmss): " + time + " date(ddmmyyyy): " + date + "\nfilename: "
            + filename + " photoFile: " + photoFile);
    return new File(filename);
}

private File getDir() {
    File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return new File(sdDir, "CustomFolder");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me

```
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, switch to using an image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso), so that your I/O and bitmap processing can be performed on a background thread.

Beyond that, hold onto the `File` object, not the `Uri`, and load the image using the `File` (e.g., `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`). This will be faster, as there will be no `ContentProvider` overhead.

Comment: Is the overhead significant? i'm dealing with a low spec device and need to understand how handling a bitmap using BitmapFactory.decodeFile() compares against MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uriImg)

Comment: @ViVekH: I do not know how you wish to measure "significant". In the end, both do file I/O. However, `decodeFile()` just does file I/O. `getBitmap()`, if `uriImg` is a `FileProvider` `Uri` from your app, will do that same file I/O, plus IPC. I don't expect the overhead to be huge for the occasional bitmap load, but it will exist.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to fetch the uri from the bitmap so considerably this code works perfactably fine :-

```
 public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: if you still faced an issue please comment i'll help.

Comment: No, I want to actually get the Bitmap. I have the image uri.

Comment: You can pass the intent in this manner and then onactivity result the response you get the bitmap.Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }

Comment: if I do that, I am returned a low quality thumbnail image.

Answer (score 0):

ADD this

```
public void onClick(View v) {   
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

when you will replace your code with this above code then automatically your this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
@Nullable Intent data){}
```

Method will Start working

```
//No Need to write this code in onclick method
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "image"+intent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```